# Playing music while recording with no re-routing

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, audiosession

I'm coding an app and I need to not interrupt any music the user is playing while the app is recording through the mic.

However, if I use kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute with kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker for my audio session properties, audio is re-routed to the external speaker even if the headphones are plugged in. If I use kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker, background music is not permitted to play even if I'm using kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers.

Any ideas?

Comment: have u set [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: nil];

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer.

Do not do this:

```
AudioSessionSetProperty( kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof( trueValue ), &trueValue );
AudioSessionSetProperty( kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker, sizeof(trueValue), &trueValue);
```

Instead, set the default speaker property first:

```
AudioSessionSetProperty( kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker, sizeof(trueValue), &trueValue);
AudioSessionSetProperty( kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof( trueValue ), &trueValue );
```

Setting the default path override seems to blow away allowing mixing with other apps. So just set allowing mixing with other apps second.

Comment: As a follow up, this has been fixed in iOS. Possibly a future version of iOS iirc.